# Div position fixed behaves different on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

I'm struggling with a Firefox behaviour regarding a `position: fixed` menu. I've made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pwsebppz/ to recreate part of my layout.

I basically have a container with `position: absolute; padding-bottom: 100px;` and a menu with `position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 75px`.

In Chrome, the menu respects the container padding and leaves a blank space of 100px, but in Firefox, the menu is overlapping the padding.

Screenshots:

[image: Firefox] 
Firefox (v 45.0.1)

[image: Chrome]
Chrome (v 49.0)

Any idea why this is happening & how to solve it?

PS: I'd rather not change the styles of the container if not necessary because (in my website) it has a reason why is absoluted positioned

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you use the same `height` of window to test it on Firefox and Chrome?

Because it is indeed overlapping when you have a lower `height` of window but both on Chrome and Firefox.

`Fixed` position and `absolute` position doesn't care about padding of other elements because they are not in the flow, so it's normal that it is overlapping when you have a lower height of window size.

**EDIT** : If you wants to keep 100px between the two parts, try this instead

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwsebppz/2/)

I separate this from the other HTML structure :

```
  <div class="l-app__bottombar">
    <p>
      My footer content
    </p>
  </div>
```

I removed `fixed` and `absolute` positions and did a `margin` instead of a `padding`.

Comment: you're right, seems I oversimplified my example and doesn't accurately reflect my real layout and its problem. I'll try to fix my fiddle. I thank you for your suggestion but  I need an element sticked to the bottom of the window so I can't remove `fixed`.